# Difference between IBM Woklight, Sencha Touch, Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, sencha-touch

I am a little confused between

- How IBM Worklight can be used with Sencha Touch?
- What is the difference between Sencha Touch and Cordova?
- Can they all be together under one development?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned the version of IBM Worklight/MobileFirst , we will assume the latest version (v8.0).

To answer your questions:

1) How IBM Worklight can be used with Sencha Touch?

Sencha Touch is a user interface (UI) JavaScript library, or web framework, specifically built for the Mobile Web. It is no longer supported and has been merged with Ext JS.

https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Sencha Touch support for IBM MobileFirst has been deprecated since v6.3 and has since been removed. Here is an early sample:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/WorklightStarter_Sencha.zip

2) What is the difference between Sencha Touch and Cordova?

Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data, network status, etc.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html

In the simplest terms, think of Sencha touch as a Javascript framework for UI. Apache Cordova gives you the capability to develop cross platform applications and access native features.

3) Can they all be together under one development?

Yes.